# finding the neighbors of code

Tags: c, arrays

We were asked to create a program that will find the neighbors of the user's input:

Here's part of what I've tried:

```
/ 
else if(lines >=0 || lines <=edges)
    {
        printf("Neighbors of node %d are: \n",lines);
        ctr=0;
        while(ctr < nodes)
        {
            fscanf(fl, "%d %d %d", &a, &b, &c);
            neighbors(a,b,c,lines);
            ctr++;
        }
     }
/
void neighbors(int alpha, int beta, int gamma, int line)
{
struct node *link = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
link-> where = alpha;
link->to = beta;
link-> much = gamma;
if(line == link-> where)
{
    printf("Node %d, cost %d\n",link->to, link->much);
}
else if(line == link-> to)
{
    printf("Node %d, cost %d\n",link->where, link->much);
}
link->next = head;
head = link;
}
/
```

It works for the first input, but for the rest, it just returns nothing. The file contains 25000 lines and three integers: int source, int dest, int cost and we have to scan which one of those lines contain the neighbor for the input.  Help? Thanks

Comment: So your program starts with "else if"?

Comment: `lines >=0 || lines <=edges` --> `lines >=0 && lines <=edges`